# Cambiar texto dinamicamente al enviar un form modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, modal

Modal-Misspass

Tengo este modal que es donde los usuarios resetean contraseñas. Y yo quisiera que luego de poner su mail y apretar restablecer, el texto cambie dinámicamente y diga "le hemos enviado un mail a su correo". Supongo que es con parent y javascript pero la verdad estoy un poco perdido. Alguien podra darme una mano?

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h2 class="modal-title" style="display:block">Restablecer Contraseña</h2>
</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="user_recovery" style='display:block'>
      <form action="misspass.php" method="POST">
              <?php if(!empty($errores)) {?>
              <div id="errores">
                <ul id="errorno">
                    <?php foreach ($errores as $error){?>
                      <li>
                      <?php echo $error;?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <?php  }}?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Introduce tu correo electrónico y te enviaremos un enlace para restablecer tu contraseña.</p>
              <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus="">
                  <button type="submit" id='botonregistrarse'class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Restablecer contraseña</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login">Volver</button>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que hacer uso del evento onsubmit de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="misspass.php" method="POST" onsubmit="cambiarTexto()">
```

Y después, haces el script (usando Jquery) con dicha función, como no aclaras el texto de qué elemento querés cambiar te anoto las tres que me imagino:

```
<script>
     function cambiarTexto() {
         $('#mail').val("le hemos enviado un mail a su correo"); // Si es que querés cambiar el valor del input
         $('#botonregistrarse').html("le hemos enviado un mail a su correo"); // Si es que querés informar a través del button
         $('p').html("le hemos enviado un mail a su correo"); // Si es que querés informar a través del <p>, CUIDADO, modificaría todos los <p>
     }
</script>
```

**Edito:**

Con el evento onchange no vas a notar el cambio porque va a modificar el texto e inmediatamente va a hacer el submit, por lo que cambiará de página. Para notar los cambios podrías hacer un AJAX que envíe las cosas, de esta forma se edita el texto y se realiza el submit sin necesidad de refrescar la página. O bien podrías hacer un submit a la misma página y manejar con PHP que analice si el mensaje se envió entonces que ejecute el script.

Espero que haya quedado más claro. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar jquery el evento change por cuestiones de tiempo no puedo especificarte exactamente el metodo

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la velocidad del programa, me explico:

1) Si tu programa es veloz, lo que yo haría es un onclick que compruebe si tiene conexión a internet, seguidamente ejecutas tu programa php y finalmente lanzas un alert diciendo lo que quieras:
if (navigator.onLine == true) {programa.php; alert('aaa')} else{alert('Compruebe su conexión a Internet')}
2) Tu programa no es veloz, es decir, se toma digamos 10 segundos en ejecutarse. La realidad desconozco php pero lo que yo hago en el lenguaje que suelo programar es lanzar un return desde el programa del lado del servidor (php en tu caso) con el mensaje que quieres y lo recoges desde javascript. Sería algo así para lo que yo programo, que imagino podrás extrapolarlo a php:
function CambioContrasena(){
....
return 'Contraseña cambiada'
}
Y en javascript recojo ese return en un alert.